# Is 'det' a metric space?

Tags: metric-spaces

suppose d is a metric on space X. I want to know that is det which define as follow a metric space or not?
$$det(x,y)=\frac{d(x,y)}{1+(d(x,y))^2}$$
hint: I know that $d^{\prime}(x.y)=\frac{d(x,y)}{1+d(x,y)}$  is a metric space

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not a metric in general, because the triangle inequality doesn't necessarily hold. Consider $\Bbb R$ with $d$ the standard metric, and see what happens when one number is very far from the two others according to $d$ (say the numbers $1,2$ and $1000$, for instance).

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to note that the function $x \mapsto \frac {x}{x + 1}$ is [concave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_function) over $[0,\infty)$ while $x \mapsto \frac{x}{x^2 + 1}$ is not.

The answer is that det, as you've defined it, will **not** be a metric (assuming that $X$ is unbounded) since it will fail the triangle inequality.

Interestingly, $x \mapsto \frac{x}{x^2 + 1}$ is concave over $[0,\sqrt{3}]$, which means that for a space $X$ with sufficiently small diameter, the function det will define a metric after all.

Comment: thank you for your answer